# How to compare two comma-separated string lists using MySQL

Tags: mysql, list

I used a Java method called 'containsAll()' to check if ArrayLists have common content.

Let's say I have a list A (one row), and several other lists in a MySQL table (in column 'name', row by row). 
All lists consist of comma-separated Strings (at least one String in a list) - names or whatever.

Now, I want to check if all Strings in list A can be found in any of the rows in column 'name'. 
The result set should show all the rows in 'name' that match, that includes rows/lists must have all Strings in list A, and can have additional Strings.

Example I

A:   'Mr.T'

```
____name_________________________________________
 'Hannibal'
 'Hannibal','Face','Murdock','Mr.T','Donald Duck'
 'Face','Donald Duck'
 'Superman','Chuck Norris','Mr.T'
_________________________________________________
```

Result set: 'Hannibal','Face','Murdock','Mr.T','Donald Duck'  -AND- 
            'Superman',Chuck Norris','Mr.T'

---

Example II

A:   'Rocky', 'Mr.T', 'Apollo'

```
 ______name__________________________________________________
 'Hannibal','Face','Murdock','Donald Duck','Superman','Mr.T'
 'Rocky','Apollo','Ivan'
 'Apollo', 'Superman','Hannibal','Rocky','Mr.T','Chuck Norris'
 'Rocky','Mr.T','Apollo','Chuck Norris'
_____________________________________________________________
```

Result set:  'Apollo', 'Superman','Hannibal','Rocky','Mr.T','Chuck Norris'  -AND- 
             'Rocky','Mr.T','Apollo','Cuck Norris'

I wonder if one can carry out those results using a MySQL query.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Looks like multi-valued fields in a DB - this is generally a warning sign of bad design.

Comment: Is there a reason why you're not using a table to store the character name values and another table to store the relationship between whatever table is storing these lists and the table containing character names? This relationship has a name - many to many - and it is not difficult to model in an RDBMS.

Comment: I am working on a little app. Well, on client-side the end-user is able to interact with an interface, whereupon a list of Strings is selected on the fly. On server-side, these String lists will be compared against the content of my MySQL DB. I already have a DB design scheme that should work. I carried out the comparison between the lists using Java only and an external flatfile. But it is toooo slow...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears you want to do an array intersection, except your array is a single column.  It can be done, but it will be slow, difficult to debug and will not leverage the power of relational databases. A better way would be to change your table schema to something like this:

Table groups

```
group_id int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key,
character_list text
```

Table members_in_group

```
group_id int unsigned not null,
group_member varchar(45) not null
```

Then you can query like this:

```
SELECT group_id, character_list
FROM groups g 
  JOIN members_in_groups m USING (group_id)
WHERE m.group_member IN ('Mr. T', ...);
```

The `groups` table is probably very like your current table.  The `members_in_groups` table is the same data chopped up into easily searchable parts.

ETA given your comment, this should work *if* you can guarantee that each `character_list` contains only *one* instance of each character:

```
SELECT group_id, 
       SUM(CASE m.group_member IN ('Mr. T', 'Apollo', 'Rocky') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS tally, 
       character_list
FROM groups g
  JOIN members_in_groups m ON (g.group_id=m.group_id)
GROUP BY group_id
  HAVING SUM(CASE m.group_member IN ('Mr. T', 'Apollo', 'Rocky') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 3;
```

In this case the `HAVING` clause must equal 3 because there are 3 members in `IN ('Mr. T', 'Apollo', 'Rocky')`.

Comment: Thx, I tested it. It's not exactly what i've been looking for. I need something like "SELECT * FROM table WHERE FIND_IN_SET('Mr.T', column_name)" but the first argument has to be a list in some cases like "...FIND_IN_SET('Mr. T','Apollo','Rocky','column_name')".

Comment: @myX.: I've extended my answer to cover the case of multiple names in a set.

Answer (score 2):

I solved this issue by using the [REGEXP](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html) function in MySQL:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `column` REGEXP("(value1|value2|value3)");
```

Comment: I think OP was looking for a 'containsAll' (logical AND) implementation, this REGEXP you have is a logical OR.

Answer (score -3):

SELECT * FROM tbl_name WHERE field_name LIKE '%\'Mr.T\'%'

Comment: what happens when he looks for 'X, Y and Z' in a row containing 'Z, X and Y'?