# Comparing unique values in Lists

Tags: mysql

This question is an extension of sorts of:
[How to compare two comma-separated string lists using MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11935750/how-to-compare-two-comma-separated-string-lists-using-mysql)

I have a `TASKS_DONE` table that has 2 columns `user_id` and `task_id`(INT). These codes are used to represent tasks performed by Users.

Separate tables `TASKS` and `USERS` are used to maintain details of Tasks and Users.

My requirement is to check if a user has done a set of tasks (say `2, 3, 5`). Currently, I have this query:

```
select * from USERS u
where
  (
    select SUM( IF(task_id in (2, 3, 5), 1, 0) )
    from TASKS_DONE td
    where td.user_id=u.user_id
    group by td.user_id
  ) = 3
```

The count (`3` in this case) will be fed to the query dynamically. The problem with this approach is, if the user has performed the same task twice, the count will include both the instances of the task. But I need to consider only the distinct set of `task_id`

Please help.

Answer (score 2):

I guess there's a place for them, but corellated subqueries just seem so icky...

```
SELECT u.* 
  FROM users u
  JOIN tasks_done td
    ON td.user_id = u.user_id
   AND td.task_id IN (2,3,5)
 GROUP
    BY u.user_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT td.task_id) = 3;
```

Comment: "The problem with this approach is, if the user has performed the same task twice, the count will include both the instances of the task."

Comment: @Strawberry Could you please comment on this?

Comment: @YaK Are you saying it wont work, or that it's inefficient? It works fine for me

Comment: @YaK ? But that's what the OP wants!?!

Comment: My apologies. I didn't notice the `DISTINCT` clause. I didn't even know this was possible. @th3an0maly, this query is to be preferred over mine. Strawberry, please edit your answer so that I can up-vote it.

Comment: Thanks guys, I tried both the solutions. They work fine. But due to simplicity of @Strawberry's solution, I'm accepting it as the right answer. Many thanks, again :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT user_id
FROM users
JOIN (
    SELECT task_id, user_id
    FROM tasks
    WHERE task_id IN (2, 3, 5)
    GROUP BY task_id, user_id
) AS unique_tasks USING (user_id)
GROUP BY user_id
HAVING COUNT(user_id) = 3
```

Then join this result set with `users` again to retrieve more information:

```
SELECT users.*
FROM users
JOIN (
    SELECT user_id
    FROM users
    JOIN (
        SELECT task_id, user_id
        FROM tasks
        WHERE task_id IN (2, 3, 5)
        GROUP BY task_id, user_id
    ) AS unique_tasks USING (user_id)
    GROUP BY user_id
    HAVING COUNT(user_id) = 3
) AS selected_users USING (user_id)
```